# Merg duplicate in Column1 while summing their values in column 3, though keep the values in column 2 (which are also duplicate) I have this code

Tags: excel, vba, merge, sum, duplicates

I am trying to merge duplicates in column A (which I can do), keep the value in column B (which I can't do) and sum values from duplicated in column A in column C (which I can do) - So, in essence, the question is how do I change the following code to include keeping the duplicate value in column B.

Thanks Dylan

```
Sub CombineRows()


Dim WorkRng As Range

Dim Dic As Variant

Dim arr As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Application.Worksheets("Shopping List").Range("A2:C1000")
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

arr = WorkRng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)

    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 3)


Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)

WorkRng.Range("C1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: use an array as the dictionary value

Answer (score 0):

try this ..... please re-enable WorkRng.ClearContents and set the destination ranges to desired values after testing

```
Sub CombineRows()

'    On Error Resume Next

    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Application.Worksheets("Shopping List").Range("A2:C1000")

    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = WorkRng.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)

        dic(arr(i, 1)) = Array(0, 0)    ' init dictionary items array (needed because of the math in next instruction)
        dic(arr(i, 1)) = Array(arr(i, 2), dic(arr(i, 1))(1) + arr(i, 3))

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    WorkRng.ClearContents

    Dim aaaa As Variant
    aaaa = dic.items
    aaaa = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aaaa)

    WorkRng.Range("e1").Resize(dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.Keys)

    WorkRng.Range("f1").Resize(dic.Count, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aaaa)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Jsotola, Thanks for getting back to me, the code allows the second row to be kept when merging though the sum of the merged quantities in column three is not occurring.   The line: dic(arr(i, 1)) = Array(arr(i, 2), dic(arr(i, 1))(1) + arr(i, 3)) is causing Run time error '13' Type mismatch.